# MySQL SUM() Returns an Empty Array Instead of Decimal Value

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, sum

I get an empty array when trying to get the sum of payments in decimal type column (4,2). Here's the code:

```
global $wpdb;
$balance = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT cast(sum(cpi) as decimal(5,2)) AS balance_value FROM hp_callbacks");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($balance);
$sum = $row['balance_value'];
echo "Result: $sum";
```

When checking $balance I can see it's an array:

```
global $wpdb;
$balance = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT cast(sum(cpi) as decimal(5,2)) AS balance_value FROM hp_callbacks");
echo "Result: $balance";
```

The output is:

```
Result: Array
```

I want to show up total balance for all rows in "cpi" column (no empty rows) as $sum. What am doing wrong? Any ideas to fix my code?
P.S. Using it in WordPress if it would be useful info...

Comment: Well, `$balance` is an array, true. Try `var_dump($balance);` to see what it contains.

Comment: If you echo an array in wp, wp show a array text to say its an array. You must use array index to display your result. First of all use print_r method and pass output to find index

Comment: Thank you, @aynber and @MohammadYousefi! I used `var_dump($balance)` and got the following output: `array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1323 (1) { ["balance_value"]=> string(4) "2.94" } }`. With `print_r` I got: `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [balance_value] => 2.94 ) ) 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array contains an object with one property called `balance_value`, so you would access that like this

```
echo "Result: " . $balance[0]->balance_value;
```

Comment: Thank you, @RiggsFolly! It works now! But I modified it a bit to use in other places of the code. `$balance = $balance[0]->balance_value;
echo "Result: $balance";`

Answer (score -1):

Just try using

```
$rownum = 0 /* put the value of the row which you want to retrieve, I want to retrieve only the first row */ 
$balance[$rownum][0]
```

The problem is caused as your code returns an array, which cannot be printed using echo. If you want to to print the array use

```
print_r($balance);
```